# Follower's items disappear after "The Final Descent" quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

Before I played said quest, I told my follower to wait outside Raven Rock Mine and then I entered. I completed the quest and read the Black Book. When I was at the point where I could choose a Black Book perk, I chose the one that makes me do no damage to my follower. When I exited the Black Book, I came back to the point where I first read it. Surprisingly, my follower, [Illia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Illia), was standing there as well, but with none of the armor/items I gave her, only her standard robes and spells.

I could reload from where I left her outside the Mine but I think the same thing will happen after I do the quest. Also, checking the wiki, I found this bug: "*Her inventory is known to reset.*"

If anyone knows a way of completing the quest without her inventory disappearing, that would be great (because the Bloodskal blade is awesome!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a simple solution (because you still have a good save file):

- Reload the save from before the quest
- Remove all important items from her inventory (probably everything)
- Do quest
- Return said inventory to follower

Also, if you are on [pc](/questions/tagged/pc) you can download [The Unofficial Skyrim Legendary Edition Patch](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214/?).
This is a very reliable mod that fixes a lot of bugs in the vanilla version of Skyrim.
And according to the [change log here](http://afkmods.iguanadons.net/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html), one of the fixes is Illia's inventory reset bug.
Just use <kbd>ctrl+f</kbd> to search for "Illia" in the change log and you will find it.

> **Actor Fixes**
>
> - Illia has been given a static spell list and flagged as unique to    prevent an issue where her inventory would reset after she had been
>     left alone for enough time. She's available as a follower and this
>     would result in any items given to her by the player being lost when
>     she resets. Also removed the leveled dagger from her inventory since
>     she was receiving an identical leveled dagger in her alias in
>     dunDarklightQST.

This also answers why you are losing the items in her inventory, you are leaving her alone for to long.